# How to store value and retrive it to use in next view controller after login using userdefaults?

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to store the `ngoid` value in `userDefaults` so that I can access it in my next API call in the next `viewController` class. How do I do it?

Here is the code I have written:

```
@IBAction func loginbutton(_ sender: Any) {
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.shreetechnosolution.com/funded/ngo_login.php")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

    let postString = "uname=\(textfieldusername.text!)&password=\(textfieldpassword.text!)";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)



    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data , response , error in

        if error != nil
        {
            //let alert = UIAlertView()
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Box !", message: "Login Failed", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        print("*****response = \(String(describing: response))")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data! , encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue )

        if ((responseString?.contains("")) == nil) {
            print("incorrect - try again")

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Try Again", message: "Username or Password Incorrect", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Nochmalversuchen", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in

            }


            // Add Actions
            alert.addAction(yesAction)


            // Present Alert Controller
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else {
            print("correct good")


        }

        print("*****response data  = \(responseString!)")




        do {
            //create json object from data

            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {

                if let email = json["UserName"] as? String,
                    let password1 = json["passowrd"] as? String {

                    print ("Found User id:  called \(email)")
                }
                let msg = (json.value(forKey: "message") as! NSString!) as String
               //let id = json.value(forKey: "NgoId") as! Int!

                let ngoid = json.value(forKey: "NgoId") as? String

                print(ngoid ?? "")

                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

                defaults.set(ngoid, forKey: "ngoid")

                print(ngoid!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Box!", message: "\(msg)", preferredStyle: .alert)
                self.action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in

                    let vtabbar1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar1")
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vtabbar1!, animated: true)


                }

                self.alert.addAction(self.action)

                self.present(self.alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }

            }
        }
        catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `UserDefaults` but if you only need to use the value on the next `viewController` you should use a segue for this purpose. [Here](http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-swift-view-controllers/) is a guide of how that works. Otherwise use UserDefaults like the example below:

```
// To set the value
UserDefaults.standard.set(ngoid, forKey: "NgoId")

// To get the value
let id = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "NgoId")
```

Comment: where do i write a set code and where do i write set code

Comment: You set the code whenever you get the value and you get it whenever you need to use it.

Comment: ok I'll will try we dont need to declare any values in app delegate? or do we

Comment: You don´t need to do that.

Comment: func loadData()
        {
             let id = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "NgoId")
            
            let url = URL(string: "http://www.shreetechnosolution.com/funded/ngo_profile.php?ngoid=\(id)")
    
            var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
    
            let session = URLSession.shared
    
    
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {(data : Data?, response : URLResponse?,error : Error?) in
    
//It is giving me error for url request

Comment: @TejalOhara, thats an error in your request does not have anything with the UserDefaults to do.

Comment: but i want that id to be attached to my api which i m requesting i m doing it with string interpolation can you plz check i m requesting api right or not

Comment: Do it like this `if let id = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "NgoId") { let url = URL(string: "shreetechnosolution.com/funded/\(id)") }` If you want the id to be attached like that in your url. print out that string and make sure that the url looks as you want it to.

Comment: this solved the problem but now i m using it in tabel view and storing the values in model class whichever i have fetched but it says

Comment: do
                {
                    let rootdictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
    
                    var rootarray = rootdictionary.object(forKey: "listngoprofile") as! NSArray
    
                    for item in rootarray
                    {
    
                        var obj = item as! NSDictionary
                         var temp = NGOdetails()
    
                        temp.Nameofngo = obj.object(forKey: "Nameofngo") as! String!

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10e404918) to 'NSString' (0x10d5fac60).
(lldb)

Comment: @TejalOhara, now you have other issues. You should ask a new question regarding these issues. Otherwise this comment field will be way to long. So accept this answer if it solved your issues with the userdafault and ask a new question. That will be much better for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a best way to save in user default and then use in next **ViewController**, use this overdid method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == "ShowCounterSegue"
{
    if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? OtherViewController {
        destinationVC.ngoid = ngoid
    }
}
```

}

use **ngoid** anywhere in your next **ViewController** api call.